# Extra space printed from overriding python class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Here is the code:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.eye_color = eye_color

    def show_info(self):
        print("The last_name -- " + self.last_name)
        print("The eye_color -- " + self.eye_color)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, last_name, eye_color, num_toys):
        Parent.__init__(self, last_name, eye_color) ##need self here
        self.num_toys = num_toys

    def show_info(self):
        print("The eye_color -- " + self.eye_color)
        print("The eye_color -- " + self.eye_color)
        print("The num_toys -- " , self.num_toys)
flint = Child("Fan", "Black", 0)
print(flint.eye_color)
flint.show_info()
```

But when `flint.show_info()` got called, this is the output:

```
Black
The eye_color --    Black
The eye_color -- Black
The num_toys --  0
```

Where did the extra space of last_name come from?
If delete the show_info from Child, the extra space will be gone. I am using python 3.5

Comment: can't reproduce. No extra spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you had a literal tab character (i.e. you pressed TAB instead of SPACE) at that position:

```
    def show_info(self):
        print("The eye_color --<<<LITERAL TAB CHARACTER>>>" + self.eye_color)
        print("The eye_color -- " + self.eye_color)
```

Ideally, you should configure the editor you're using to make tab characters and spaces visible, so you can easily identify and discern them.

Also, best practices and style guides for Python recommend not to use tab characters in your source code at all. As they may be visually indistinguishable from space characters (as in your case) and may advance to widely different tab stop values (such as 8, 4 or any other odd value).

Comment: oh..yeah...because I used to use Xcode,,then I got used to press tab in order to move the cursor over the quotation mark.. thanks